# Tensorflow object detection API running with CUDA

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

When I try to run tensorflow object detection API on my custom dataset I get the error message below. The process is just killed. Is it related to the computer memory in some way? Maybe CUDA version or tensorflow version? I have tensorflow-gpu version 1.13.1 and CUDA version 10.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
Killed
```

Comment: Killed means the Out of Memory Manager killed it, so yes, it is using more RAM than the system has.

Comment: This question plainly has nothing to do with CUDA programming, which is why I removed the tag. Twice. Let's keep it like that.